# Thunderbird problem

Tags: thunderbird

I get the following message when I click on GetMail. However, the inbox is already empty.
I also get a similar message when I try to delete a message

"The folder Inbox is full, and can't hold any more messages. To make room for more messages, delete any old or unwanted mail and compact the folder."

Comment: Have you tried to "repair folder" ? Right click to the problematic folder and open properties. There you will see the repair option.

Answer (score 0):

"The folder Inbox is full, and can't hold any more messages. To make room for more messages, delete any old or unwanted mail and compact the folder."

This is a very clear message.

According to Mozilla:

> The Inbox should be used as an Inbox for new incoming mail and not
>   used as a general store. Each Folder displayed in the Folder Pane is
>   actually an mbox file, with emails written one after the other in the
>   order they were downloaded. So you are currently storing all those
>   emails in one single file which must be rather large to get that
>   message.
>
> Do this to resolve the situation:
>
> - Create some folders with suitable names to organize your emails. eg:    'Family', 'Friends', 'Clients, 'Thunderbird', 'Online Orders', 
>     'Bills' etc.
> - Then move emails from Inbox into the appropriate folder(s).
> - Delete any emails you do not want.
> - When Inbox is empty, right click on Inbox folder and select    'compact'.

When compacting is finished, click on GetMail.